# VB.NET Transferring ListBox and Textbox Data

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox

I'm trying to transfer textbox data and listbox data into a separate listbox and I'm not sure how to. For example:

- ListBox1 contains "Soup"
- TextBox contains a value "4"

I want ListBox2 to show "4 Soup" when I click a button that says add. I know how to add them both separately. Is there a way I can add both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use & to concatenate the two strings into one and add the resulting string to the Items collection of ListBox2. Don't forget to check that you have an item selected in ListBox1.

```
If ListBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then 
    ListBox2.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text & " " & ListBox1.SelectedItem)
End If
```

Comment: `ListBox2.Items.Add(Trim(TextBox1.Text) & " " & Trim(ListBox1.SelectedItem))`

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I overlooked something so simple. Gah.